# Node JS: evaluate value inside array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, for-loop

I have data that looks like this

```
[
  [ '@test','1.2.6' ],
  [ '@test2','4.0.1' ],
  [ '@test3','2.2.0-unstable' ],
...
]
```

and I would like to retrieve all the values that have appended `-unstable` and list both the name `@test3` and the value `2.2.0-unstable` and perform actions on that

I've tried this but I'm nowhere near

```
  axios.request(config)
  .then((response) => {
    const myArray = response.data.value.reduce((acc, next) => { acc.push(...next.versions.map(v => [next.normalizedName, v.normalizedVersion])); return acc }, [])

  myArray.forEach(function(value){
        if ((value === '-unstable')) {
          // do some stuff
    } 
  });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays, or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: I checked that but it was just not quite right. Have accepted @mandy8055's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using ***[`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)*** function to filter out only the elements with `-unstable` in the version then performing your desired actions. Something like:

```js
// ... Your axios code to fetch the data and put to myArray

    // Filter the array to get the values with appended '-unstable'
   const unstableArray = myArray.filter(([_, version]) => version.includes('-unstable'));

   // Perform actions on the filtered values
   unstableArray.forEach(([name, version]) => {
     // Do some stuff...   
    });
});
```

```js
const myArray = [
  ['@test', '1.2.6'],
  ['@test2', '4.0.1'],
  ['@test3', '2.2.0-unstable'],
  ['@test4', '2.2.10-unstable'],
  ['@test5', '2.2.1-stable'],

];

const unstableArray = myArray.filter(([_, version]) => version.includes('-unstable'));

unstableArray.forEach(([name, version]) => {
  console.log(`Name: ${name}, Version: ${version}`);
});
```